# AlertDialog trouble (Empty?)

Tags: android, dialog

I'm making a simple game where you place tiles to grow hotel chains and increase your wealth strategically. At certain points, you're given the option to choose what kind of hotel you'd like to create and the following dialogBox should be shown.

Here's the Code:

```
public void convertToHotelDialog(final Tile tile){

    if(AVAILABLE_HOTELS.size() != 0){
        String[] tempHotel = new String[AVAILABLE_HOTELS.size()];
        AlertDialog.Builder hotelDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        hotelDialog.setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.hotel_dialog_title));
        hotelDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.hotel_dialog_message));

        for (int i = 0; i < AVAILABLE_HOTELS.size(); i++) {
            tempHotel[i] = new String();
            tempHotel[i] = AVAILABLE_HOTELS.get(i);
        }

        hotelDialog.setItems(tempHotel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                String hotelName = AVAILABLE_HOTELS.get(which);
                convertToHotel(tile, getHotelCodeByName(hotelName));
            }
        });

        hotelDialog.show();             
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder hotelDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        hotelDialog.setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.hotel_dialog_title));
        hotelDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.hotel_dialog_fail_message));
        hotelDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I've run the debugger and stepped my way through it. It IS stepping through the **IF** portion of the code but the dialog box shows up completely empty.
The title is correct, but the message and the spinner just don't exist.

Perhaps I don't understand completely how setItems works?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance,
JRad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to make a list inside the dialog, i use a method like that to make a list of telephones on my app:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon);
builderSingle.setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.hotel_dialog_title));
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterHotels = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, AVAILABLE_HOTELS);
builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapterHotels,
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        String hotelName = AVAILABLE_HOTELS.get(which);
        convertToHotel(tile, getHotelCodeByName(hotelName));
    }
});
builderSingle.show();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow. That's so smooth. I removed the cancel button since they HAVE to choose a hotel but that's great. Thanks so much. If you don't mind, I kind of want to understand WHY my code wasn't working as excepted though. How come it was blank? Understanding they why will help me avoid this kind of issue in the future.

Comment: Actually I dont't know, as i never used the setItems method, I have always used the way I posted in my answer.